# Conceptual problem in Theory Of Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While doing some self-study from the book: **Higher Algebra by Hall & Knight**, I encountered some articles that I could not understand properly. Those articles were **Art. 562 & Art. 563**.

**Art 562**: The result of the preceding article(given below) enables us very easily to find the sum of an assigned power of the roots of an equation.

Result of preceding article: $f'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)}+\frac{f(x)}{(x-b)}+....+\frac{f(x)}{(x-k)}$,

where a,b,....,k are the roots of the equation $f(x)=0$

**Art 563**: When the coefficients are numerical we may also proceed as in the following example.

**Here is where the problem lies**

**Example**: Find the sum of the fourth powers of the roots of

$$x^3-2x^2+x-1=0$$

Here $f(x)=x^3-2x^2+x-1$,   $f'(x)=3x^2-4x+1$. $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{1}{x-b}+\frac{1}{x-c}$$
$$=\sum{\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{a}{x^2}+\frac{a^2}{x^3}+....\Bigl)\qquad\qquad...(1)$$
$$=\frac{3}{x}+\frac{S_1}{x^2}+\frac{S_2}{x^3}+\frac{S_3}{x^4}+.....;\qquad\qquad...(2)$$

hence $S_4$ is equal to the coefficient of $\frac{1}{x^5}$  in the quotient of $f'(x)$ by $f(x)$, which is very conveniently obtained by the **method of synthetic division** as follows:

[image]

Hence the quotient is $\frac{3}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x^3}+\frac{5}{x^4}+\frac{10}{x^5}+.....;$ thus $S_4=10$.

I could not understand the method of synthetic division and the steps (1) and (2).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thank you...it was really helpful

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I couldn't find any example showing the division of a polynomial by a polynomial of higher degree...where can I get one?

Comment: Pretend the numerator is $x^{1000}(3x^2-4x+1)$ rather than $3x^2-4x+1$.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x$ such that $|x|>\max (|a|,|b|,|c|)$ and for each $d\in \{a,b,c\}$ we have $$\frac {1}{x-d}=(1/x)\cdot\frac {1}{1-d/x}=(1/x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(d/x)^n=$$   $$=(1/x)+(d/x^2)+(d^2/x^3)+...$$  If we sum this over each of the 3 series with $d=a, d=b$ and $d=c,$ the resulting co-efficient  of $x^{-5}$ is $a^4+b^4+c^4.$

Imagine that $f(x$) and $f'(x)$ are representations of numbers  in number-base $x,$ although we allow the digits (the co-efficients) to be any numbers, not just integers from $0$ to $x-1.$ Synthetic division follows the same rules of long division that  you would use for computing all of the digits (co-efficients) of all integer-powers of of the base, including especially  the negative powers.